# How to check if front camera exists on current device?

Tags: java, android

I use the following code for working with camera:

```
mMediaRecorderVideo=new MediaRecorder();
mCamera=Camera.open();      
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
mCamera.unlock();
mMediaRecorderVideo.setCamera(mCamera);
mMediaRecorderVideo.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
mMediaRecorderVideo.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
mMediaRecorderVideo.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
```

So, I use default camera of device, but I need to set front camera if it's possible. Please, tell me, how can I check it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int numCameras= Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for(int i=0;i<numCameras;i++){
    Camera.CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
    if(CAMERA_FACING_FRONT == info.facing){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

If you want to get the number of the front facing camera, return i instead and 0 on not found.